# WebView inside ListView is not scrollable

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have been working on a very simple task , yet it has annoyed me so much that I have pulled off each hair strand from my head (proverbial - I am already bald)

I have a simple LISTVIEW . in the template for the row . i have just ONE WebView .

I need to have a webview because I would be rendering some html which contains links etc , also the number of rows wont exceed 5 at most in the listview.

My Activity code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AboutMofa" >



         <ListView
        android:id="@+id/aboutContentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
```

My Template for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="@dimen/aboutContentBox" />
```

and my adaptor getView

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view_row, parent, false);

    WebView w = (WebView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.webviewContent);
    w.loadUrl("www.yahoo.com");

    return rowView;
```

as far as i understand it has something to do with the listview absorbing the touches and not letting the webview receive them , hence disallowing me to scroll.

Please aid me .

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can show formatted HTML inside TextViews too if you need that.

Anyways, override the onTouch of the ListView, call the super method and then return false. The event isn't consumed because you return false and the action that is supposed to start starts anyways.